# Working with values from array, containing multiple vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, cout

So basically I have created an array containing two vectors, and I want to be able to change/output values. I have read that the following syntax should work, but when I run the program, it just keeps filling up the memory without printing anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::array<std::vector<float>, 2> endPieceV;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i+2) {
        endPieceV[0].push_back(i);
        endPieceV[1].push_back(i*i+2);
    }

    std::cout << "Vector 1:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < endPieceV[0].size(); i++) {
        std::cout << endPieceV[0][i] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Vector 2:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < endPieceV[0].size(); i++) {
        std::cout << endPieceV[1][i] << " ";
    }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't start printing, but just keeps loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not incrementing i in first loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i+2) {
        endPieceV[0].push_back(i);
        endPieceV[1].push_back(i*i+2);
    }
```

Notice `i+2`  should be `i+=2`

Comment: You just saved my day. I have been searching for solutions most of the day.

Comment: Mark as answer if it helped you.

Comment: I have to wait 7 minutes, but I will ;)

Answer (score 1):

This loop counter is is incorrect:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i+2)
```

You're not incrementing `i` in this loop.

Another potential error is that you're using the wrong vector as the loop counter:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < endPieceV[0].size(); i++) {
                            // ^ Wrong, should be 1
        std::cout << endPieceV[1][i] << " ";
```

Even though you mentioned that the vectors are the same size, this is really not the way to write a loop like this.

Comment: The Vectors are of the same size - it's not an error.

Comment: @bgaard  Each one of those vectors are resizable and independent of each other.  Yes, you wrote a toy program, but it is a mistake to write code like this.  If you want to ensure the vectors are the same size, you don't assume it -- write the code to ensure it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind the next time I use the command.